# Is it possible to run rsync dry-run, confirm, then real run in one command (without having to give the password again)?

Tags: ssh, rsync, ssh-tunneling

Now, working from home, I do some work on my home computer (because the vnc connection is too slow for it) and some on my work computer (because it is only possible there).

Therefore I have a copy of the folder (and all of its contents) in which I keep the work on both computers. I use rsync to keep them up to date (though an ssh-tunnel that passes an ssh-gateway server). Since I often have to update in each direction, it can sometimes get confusing. So I like to do a dry-run to make sure I'm not about to overwrite new work on one computer because I accidentally modified a file on the other computer, or to avoid other possible conflicts.

However, this means that I need to run the command two times, once with the `-n` option and once without. I could easily avoid by writing a script, the problem is, though, that it also means I have to type my password to connect remotely two times.

I'd like to be able to just run one command, where I need to enter the password only once, that does the dry run, and waits for my confirmation by pressing "enter" or "y" or something (or cancellation) and then does the real sync. Is this possible?

---

**Edit** for extra clarification:

What I'm trying to do exactly is the following:
First I establish an ssh tunnel via the gateway server: `ssh -N -L 2222:workcomputer:22 me@gatewayserver` (which asks me for the password for `me@gatewayserver`). Then I use `rsync -ruve "ssh -p 2222" me@localhost:~/folder ~/folder` which asks me the password for `me@workcomputer` and which is the one I don't want to have to give multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup a connection going through a gateway by doing an initial ssh connection to the final machine and specifying the gateway as *jumphost* with `-J`.
Adding `-N -M` leaves this connection open so that future
ssh commands to the final machine get multiplexed over that first connection.

Put at the start of your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
ControlPath ~/.ssh/master-%r@%h:%p
```

then connect once with:

```
$ ssh -J me@gatewayserver -N -M me@workcomputer
```

It should ask you for the password to the gateway, then the password to the workcomputer. Once connected you can run commands without any passwords, eg

```
$ ssh me@workcomputer hostname
$ rsync -nv myfile me@workcomputer:/tmp
```

You can also add `-v` to the first ssh so that you can see what happens. 
The `-v` verbose output will show a socket being made in `~/.ssh`:

```
debug1: setting up multiplex master socket
debug1: channel 0: new [/home/me/.ssh/master-me@workcomputer:22]
```

Now, when you need another ssh to the same destination it will use this existing one:

```
$ ssh me@workcomputer pwd
```

gives the verbose output:

```
debug1: multiplexing control connection
debug1: channel 1: new [mux-control]
debug1: channel 2: new [client-session]
debug1: Sending command: pwd
debug1: channel 2: free: client-session, nchannels 3
debug1: channel 1: free: mux-control, nchannels 2
```

The same is true for your rsync commands:

```
$ rsync -nv myfile me@workcomputer:/tmp
sent 43 bytes  received 19 bytes  124.00 bytes/sec
total size is 173  speedup is 2.79 (DRY RUN)
```

output:

```
debug1: multiplexing control connection
...
debug1: Sending command: rsync --server -vne.LsfxC . /tmp
```

Comment: you can use  `ssh -f ...` to have the ssh command go to the background after you have entered the 2 passwords, which should allow a following command to run.

Comment: Yes, but note the `-f` has to be given as an option at the `me@workcomputer`

Comment: And as a final addition for the script `ssh -O exit me@workcomputer` will close the ssh session. Nice, that's a wrap. Thanks for the help.